# Applescript open local HTML file with Safari

Tags: safari, applescript

I'm trying to open a local html using Safari with the following script:

```
on run
set myPath to (path to me) as text
set myFolderPath to POSIX file (do shell script "dirname " & POSIX path of quoted form of myPath) & ":" as string
set _thispath to myFolderPath & "data:Default.html"

tell application "Safari"
    activate
    open (_thispath)
end tell
```

end run

However, the file is trying to open with an apendix of file:/// (an extra slash)
Anyone have any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

The extra slash is not your problem. First you want to get the "quoted form of the posix path" not the "posix path of the quoted form". That's causing you problems. Plus you aren't converting things to text properly. Anyway, try it this way...

```
set myPath to path to me
set myFolderPath to POSIX file (do shell script "dirname " & quoted form of POSIX path of myPath)
set _thispath to (myFolderPath as text) & ":data:Default.html"

tell application "Safari"
    activate
    open (_thispath)
end tell
```